# Counting non-missing occurrences

Tags: r, subset, missing-data

I need help counting the number of non-missing data points across files and subsetting out only two columns of the larger data frame.

I was able to limit the data to only valid responses, but then I struggled getting it to return only two of the columns.

I found http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html and tried their solution, but myvars did not house my column label, it return the vector of data (1:10).  My code was:

```
myvars <- c("key")
answer <- data_subset[myvars]
answer
```

But instead of printing out my data subset with only the "key" column, it returns the following errors:
"Error in `[.data.frame`(observations_subset, myvars) : undefined columns selected"  and "Error: object 'answer' not found

Lastly, I'm not sure how I count occurrences.  In Excel, they have a simple "Count" function, and in SPSS you can aggregate based on the count, but I couldn't find a command similarly titled in R.  The incredibly long way that I was going to go about this once I had the data subsetted was adding in a column of nothing but 1's and summing those, but I would imagine there is an easier way.

Comment: Are you sure the column name `key` is correctly spelled and actually exists in the data? You may also want to try it with `[[` i.e. `data_subset[["key"]]`

Comment: To check, use `names(data_subset)` to print all the column names. Or check directly with `"key" %in% names(data_subset)`.

Comment: @RichardScriven it should work both ways. `[` returns a `data.frame` and `[[` returns a `vector`.

Comment: Right, but `length(data["key"])` is probably not the same as `length(data[["key"]])`

Comment: Your'e right, but I don't see how that applies here (although it's certainly handy to know)

Answer (score 0):

To count unique occurrences, use `table`.

For example:

```
# load the "iris" data set that's built into R
data(iris)

# print the count of each species
table(iris$Species)
```

Take note of the handy function `prop.table` for converting a `table` into proportions, and of the fact that table can actually take a second argument to get a cross-tab. There's also an argument `useNA`, to include missing values as unique items (instead of ignoring them).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you wanted.

Creating some data as it was mentioned in the post as multiple files.

```
set.seed(42)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
set.seed(49)
d2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:8), 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
```

Create a list with datasets as the list elements

```
l1 <- mget(ls(pattern="d\\d+"))
```

Create a index to subset the list element that has the maximum non-missing elements

```
indx <- which.max(sapply(l1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))))
```

`Key` of columns to subset from the `larger` (non-missing) dataset

```
 key <- c("V2", "V3")
```

Subset the dataset

```
l1[[indx]][key]
 #   V2 V3
 #1  1  1
 #2  1  3
 #3  0  0
 #4  4  5
  #5  7  8

 names(l1[indx])
#[1] "d2"
```